# Changing the database at runtime in Grails application

Tags: database, grails

I am wondering if there is a way to change the database at runtime in grails - e.g., in most commercial/opensource CMS, they allow the database server to be hosted elsewhere, and you can specify the address in some config screen at runtime.

since grails configs the database server using DataSource.groovy, how does one access the internals of this, and change the database url? or database type even?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Databases and Environments](http://grails.org/doc/1.0.x/guide/3.%20Configuration.html#3.3.1 DataSources and Environments) in the Grails documentation.

Also see [Externalized Configuration](http://grails.org/doc/1.0.x/guide/3.%20Configuration.html#3.4 Externalized Configuration) if the above doesn't completely meet your needs.

Grails doesn't care where the DB resides as long as it is accessible via JDBC, so having the DB server elsewhere isn't a problem, just a configuration.

Comment: hhmm, thats pretty awesome - I didn't notice that part of the doco!